# Slow work of transitions between fragments in the ViewPager

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 5 Fragments in the `ViewPager`. Initialize `ViewPager` in `MainActivity`:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    CalendarFragment scheduleFragment = new CalendarFragment(); // this should be in getItem()
    ServicesFragment servicesFragment = new ServicesFragment(); // this should be in getItem()
    ReviewsFragment reviewsFragment = new ReviewsFragment(); // this should be in getItem()
    NotificationFragment notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment(); // this should be in getItem()
    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment(); // this should be in getItem()

    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(scheduleFragment); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(servicesFragment); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(reviewsFragment); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(notificationFragment); // this line can cause crashes
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(profileFragment); // this line can cause crashes

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}
```

And in `ProfileFragment` I work with `google Maps`. I initialize to `onCreateView()`:

```
if (mMap == null) {
    final OnMapReadyCallback mapListener = this;
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        if (isAdded()) {
            mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(mapListener);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Tried to initialize on `onViewCreated()` and `onResume()`, the result is the same.

So the problem is that when I press 4 of 5 menu items, it hangs for half a second. Since when you click on the 4-Fragment `NotificationFragment`, simultaneously with it, a 5-fragment `ProfileFragment` is created, that is, they work:

> ```
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onAttach()
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onCreateView()
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onViewCreated()
> D/== Profile Fragment ==: onResume()
> ```

Questions:

- Is it possible to make sure that when you click on the menu items, only those methods that are relevant to this `fragment` that I clicked on are triggered, and not finding the `fragments` along with it were initialized next?
- or so, but the google map initialization in `ProfileFragment` did not delay the main thread?

**UPD:**

I just realized that the opening of the `Fragment` is slow because of `layout`, that is because of `Google Maps` fragment and not because of `OnMapReadyCallback`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When I remove a `google maps` from `layout.xml`, it works quickly. But I need `google maps`. So now what to do, how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `viewPagerAdapter.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`, this will cache the fragments that are not in use

Answer (score 0):

The default off screen limit when you use a view pager is `1`. That means immediate next neighbour fragments will always be cached. The lag for you is because the `ProfileFragment` is also init when you open the fragment next to it.

You can override `setUserVisibleHint` to init things in this fragment only when the fragment is visible to the user.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // load map
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but It turned out that this was not the problem

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: I have not decided yet. Updated question